# Building a sparse matrix using a big, dense 2d array in Python, using Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am using Python and Scipy library to create a sparse matrix, specifically csr_matrix (Compressed Sparse Row Matrix). The matrix is rather big, about 70000*70000 elements. I build the matrix as a 2d array and then construct the csr_matrix, giving the 2d array as an argument. Constructing a very sparse matrix of the size is easily done without any issues.

The problem rises when giving a denser 2d array (much less zero elements), the process is interrupted with an error:

> Value Error: unrecognized csr_matrix constructor usage

I tried building a dense matrix in the interactive Python environment with the same size and got exactly the same error.

```
from scipy import sparse
a = [[10 for i in range(70000)] for j in range(70000)]
mat = sparse.csr_matrix(a)
```

So my question is:

-Does constructing the csr_matrix depend on how sparse the 2d array is? What is the limit?

-How can I be sure the program wouldn't be interrupted in the middle of processing with such errors?

-Any alternative solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With smaller numbers your method works:

```
In [20]: a=[[10 for i in range(1000)] for j in range(1000)]
In [21]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(a)
In [22]: M
Out[22]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 1000000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Density is not the issue.  Size probably is.  I can't reproduce your error because when I try larger sizes my machine slows to a crawl and I have to interrupt the process.

As given in the documentation, `csr_matrix` takes several kinds of input.  It recognizes them based on the number of elements.  I'd have to look at the code to remember the exact logic.  But one method expects a tuple of 3 arrays or lists, another a tupe of 2 items, with the second being another tuple.  The third is a numpy array.  Your case, a list of lists doesn't fit any of those, but it probably trys to turn it into an array.

```
a = np.array([[10 for i in range(M)] for j in range(N)])
```

Most likely your error message is the result of some sort memory error - you are trying to make too large of a matrix.  A dense matrix 70000 square is big (at least on some machines) and a sparse one representing the same matrix will be even larger.  It has to store each of the elements 3 times - once for value, and twice for coordinates.

A truely sparse matrix of that size works because the sparse representation is much smaller, roughly proportional to 3x the number of nonzero elements.

---

In `scipy/sparse/compressed.py`

```
class _cs_matrix(...):
    """base matrix class for compressed row and column oriented matrices"""
    def __init__(self, arg1, ...):
        <is arg1 a sparse matrix>
        <is arg1 a tuple>
       else:
            # must be dense
            try:
                arg1 = np.asarray(arg1)
            except:
                raise ValueError("unrecognized %s_matrix constructor usage" % self.format)
```

My guess it that it tries:

```
np.asarray([[10 for i in range(70000)] for j in range(70000)])
```

and that results in some sort of error, most likely 'too large' or 'memory'.  That error is caught, and reissued with this 'unrecognized ..' message.

Try

```
A = np.array(a)
M = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
```

I suspect it will give you a more informative error message.

Comment: What you said is convincing. Although building A as a Numpy array will consume much more memory and I couldn't test your suggested code afterwards (to get the exact message), the previous error is more clear to me now. I will try to solve the memory problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the last two examples on creating sparse matrices:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

You probably can find the answers to your other questions in the documentation as well

Comment: The last two examples are using another type of instantiation, csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), [shape=(M, N)]). Well, I don't have those three arrays (data, indices and indptr); in fact, I just want them. Besides, I don't want to see a representation of a dense matrix, I already have it. My question is, whether the number of not zero elements causes a problem in constructing a matrix or not.

Comment: @SaraJavadzadeh, we are talking about sparse matrices, so if you have a a matrix with very few zeros in it, than it is not sparse, despite representing in a sparse matrix data structure...

Comment: That's right. But still two questions remains. Firstly, the error message is strange, it doesn't include any information on density. Secondly, I want to know how much sparsity is enough for csr_matrix.

Comment: @SaraJavadzadeh, have you tried any one of the other sparse matrices in `scipy`? I think the error you get is because your matrix is not in fact sparse